# Unknown Error in numpy module addition to windows python 2.7

Tags: windows, python-2.7, numpy, setup.py

**This is the error i am getting while running the setup.py Any Ideas what to do about it?? I have tried coping the folder in python directory and all other things possible. The numpy source is downloaded from official directory.**

```
C:\Python27\numpy-1.8.2>python setup.py install
Running from numpy source directory.
C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option:
 'test_suite'
  warnings.warn(msg)
non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
F2PY Version 2
blas_opt_info:
blas_mkl_info:
  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python
27\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_info:
  libraries  not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python27\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', '
C:\\Python27\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_info:
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\
Python27\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Python27\numpy-1.8.2\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1521: UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
blas_info:
  libraries blas not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python27\\libs'
]
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Python27\numpy-1.8.2\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1530: UserWarning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
blas_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Python27\numpy-1.8.2\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1533: UserWarning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
    the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
  NOT AVAILABLE

non-existing path in 'numpy\\lib': 'benchmarks'
lapack_opt_info:
lapack_mkl_info:
mkl_info:
  libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python
27\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Python27\lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python27\lib
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Python27\libs
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python27\libs
numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_info:
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Python27\lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python27\lib
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Python27\libs
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python27\libs
numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Python27\numpy-1.8.2\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1427: UserWarning:
    Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
    the ATLAS environment variable.
  warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
lapack_info:
  libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python27\\lib
s']
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Python27\numpy-1.8.2\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1438: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
    the LAPACK environment variable.
  warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
lapack_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Python27\numpy-1.8.2\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1441: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
  warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option:
 'define_macros'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running install
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler opti
ons
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler opt
ions
running build_src
build_src
building py_modules sources
building library "npymath" sources
No module named msvccompiler in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

C:\Python27\numpy-1.8.2>
```

Comment: Do you need to compile it yourself? If so, maybe look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20347252/cant-install-numpy-1-8-with-python-2-7-under-windows-7?rq=1 is a similar question.. any other replies regarding this??