# How to properly upgrade numpy on Windows 7?

Tags: python, numpy, windows-7

It seems the whole world is using Linux or Mac, and I couldn't find any answer on the web to question "How to properly upgrade numpy on **Windows 7**?". I use Windows 7, python 2.7 and numpy 1.7.1, how do I upgrade to numpy 1.9.1 on my machine?

Comment: That depends on how you installed numpy in the first place.

Comment: I see numpy 1.71. on Control Panel/Uninstall programs list

Answer (score 2):

It will be based on your installation.

- First: try `pip install --upgrade numpy`
- also try here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
- also see:   [Can't install numpy 1.8 with python 2.7 under windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20347252/cant-install-numpy-1-8-with-python-2-7-under-windows-7)

Comment: 'pip install -upgrade numpy' gave me an error saying "no such option: -u" but 'pip install --upgrade numpy' did the work for me

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is uninstall numpy and install again. When you uninstall, it will delete the older version of numpy from your computer. When you install with pip again it will install recent version of numpy.

```
pip uninstall numpy #removes numpy with older version
pip install   numpy #install new version of numpy
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have installed `numpy 1.7` using `windows binary installer`, as you can see `numpy` uninstall in Control Panel.

So best way to upgrade `numpy` is to uninstall your current version and download windows binary of recent desired version from:

[Sourceforge numpy Download](https://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/)

This link has all `numpy` version and most have windows binary ready for download.